# how to upload an excel file (exceljs) to s3

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-sdk, exceljs

I am trying to change locally a excel file and then upload it to s3.

```
var s3 = new aws.S3({ accessKeyId: config._ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: config._SECRET_ACCESS_KEY });

var dataFile = await wb.xlsx.readFile(file).then(function () {
  var sh = wb.getWorksheet(config._sheetname);
  for (let i = 2; i <= sh.rowCount; i++) {
    let currRow = sh.getRow(i);
    if (currRow.getCell(1).text == product_code) {
      currRow.getCell(2).value = product_name
      currRow.commit();
    }
  }
  let updatedfile = wb.xlsx.writeFile(file).then(rs => { console.log('edit filed successfully ') });
  return updatedfile
})

const params = {
  Bucket: config._BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: config._filename
};
s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) { console.log(err) }
  let newversionId = data.VersionId!
  console.log("Successfully uploaded data ", newversionId);
})
```

But the file uploaded is empty...I should add body in the param. But I don't know what should it be the value since it's a excel file. Any ideas?

Comment: Typo? `let newversionId = data.VersionId!`

Comment: Also, you're not passing `Body` to `putObject`, there's no content. `Bucket` and `Key` only tell where to store an object, not what is in it.

Comment: that make sens thank you very much @cviejo what should I write in body? the await value?

Comment: Did you success upload a "normal" file to S3?

Comment: yes, you just have to write the content you want in body. Since this one is an excel file, I don't really know what to write in body...

Comment: Keep in your mind, the excel file just a "normal" file.

Comment: As explained by @hoangdv, this is just a regular file. The type doesn't matter much other than setting the contentType on s3, which is not always needed. Your variable `dataFile` is not the file, that's just an object representation of the contents. You want to use `createReadStream(file)` and use the returning stream as body.

Comment: @cviejo yes with a stream it works but with the "normal file" it doesn't... the data that is saved is unreadable. Thank you very much